# best open source software for voice chat in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, voip

I recently started working on a project with a remote developer and we want to be able to talk verry easy over VOIP.
We are both on ubuntu and have tried using skype, but it gets all kinds of weird errors and the mic isnt working.

What alternatives do you guys use to talk over the internet. 
I found this service https://voxli.com/ that allows you to easily create a chat online but it does not suport linux :(

Comment: Update Skype to 2.1beta, it works much better

Comment: @vava - I'll second that. The new beta is streets ahead of the previous version, though there's still room for improvement. They made a smart choice by letting pulseaudio handle all the linux sound system complexities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think GTalk works on linux... Look at [Tapioca](http://tapioca-voip.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tapioca)
Look at the [Telepathy client for gnome](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/telepathy-gnome).

Here is a link to the [GTalk client reference page](http://www.google.com/talk/otherclients.html).
And the [**Pidgin**](http://www.pidgin.im/) [FAQ](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#VoiceandVideoMicrophoneandWebcamSupport).

Try Pidgin first.

Answer (score 3):

When you care about being able talk to multiple developers at once I would recommend [Teamspeak](http://www.teamspeak.com/) or [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) (Ubuntu has packages for both). Both provide excellent audio quality and I found them much less troublesome then the classic VOIP solutions.

Comment: really interesting sollutions but that would envolve setting up a server. i would prefer a hosted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Support for voice and video was recently added to [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)

Answer (score 2):

I've heard [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) is quite good. I've never tried it, though.

Comment: It also supports SIP for audio and video.